# How to implement BitmapFactory in a singleton pattern on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, singleton, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am trying to implement a Singleton pattern, however when I try to use the Bitmap to create image, it says cannot resolve method getResources(). I have left a sample code below as to what I am trying to achieve.

```
private static Singleton instance = null;
public static synchronized Singleton getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new Singleton (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.singleton_image), 142, 90, 4);
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to do with that, but `getResources()` is a public method available under any Context(Activity, Service) any thing that inherits from Context.

You can edit the method to be like this

```
public static synchronized Singleton getInstance(Context context){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new Singleton (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.singleton_image), 142, 90, 4);
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried to do that however I get an error saying I cannot apply context in.

I am trying to create implement the Singleton pattern for the main player in my game, however when I try to draw the image the pattern doesn't allow me to use BitmapFactory's getResources()

Comment: how did you call the method?

Comment: The getResources() method is a one that is built into Android Studio. I have used similar code before and it has worked because I used the Singleton pattern I think that this method isn't working. I have been trying to look for an alternative but I am unable to find one yet.

Comment: Android studio has nothing to do with the methods involved, you can write the same app in any other editor.